# Variable Numpy Reshaping

Tags: python, list, numpy

In Python, I have a list of values that I need broken up into smaller arrays based upon values in another array. For example, I have this array of digits:

```
[6,5,3,1,4,3,2,4,1,3,6,1]
```

And I need it to turn into this array:

```
[[6,5,3],[1,4],[3,2],[4],[1,3,6],[1]]
```

Given that I have this array specifying the lengths of the broken up parts:

```
[3,2,2,1,3,1]
```

I have tried looking at the numpy reshape documentation, and this function seems to do what I want, but I am not sure how to make it work without modifying the whole array and doing it in essentially a 'variable' way. I have also tried doing it through for loops but cannot seem to get the indices to work correctly.

Comment: Be clear, when are you talking about Python `lists`, and when `numpy` `arrays`.  Or are you just using `array` to mean the same as lists.

Comment: `numpy` does have a `split` function, but all it does is take a bunch of slices.  Sticking with your list:  `[alist[0:3], alist[3:5], alist[5:7], alist[7:8],....]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to incur the additional cost of removing items from a list, here's one way of doing it, using `itertools.islice()`:

```
iterator = iter(my_list)
my_result = [list(islice(iterator, length)) for length in my_lens]
```

**Testing it out:**

```
from itertools import islice

my_list = [6,5,3,1,4,3,2,4,1,3,6,1]
my_lens = [3,2,2,1,3,1]

iterator = iter(my_list)
my_result = [list(islice(iterator, length)) for length in my_lens]
print(my_result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[6, 5, 3], [1, 4], [3, 2], [4], [1, 3, 6], [1]]
```

Comment: You don't need 0 as the start of islice, it is the default. Just islice(iterator, length).

Comment: @Veky, True, but arguably, it helps readability to mention the start anyway.

Comment: For me, it is the same as range. If you're regularly writing range(0, 5) instead of range(5), then I understand you, but I doubt it. :-]

Comment: @Veky, you win -- I regularly use `range(5)` rather than `range(0,5)`. I'll edit the answer to get rid of the `0`

Comment: In fact, I understand your uneasiness. That "start" parameter is the only place in core Python where default arguments don't go "from the end" -1, -2, -3, but -1, -3, -2. But since we're so used to it with range, it would be a shame not to use the same idiom here; more so, since in my experience, we islice from the start even more often than we range from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sum of the lengths are always same as length of the list, you can use `list.pop(0)`:

```
l = [6,5,3,1,4,3,2,4,1,3,6,1]
[[l.pop(0) for _ in range(i)] for i in [3,2,2,1,3,1]]
```

Output:

```
[[6, 5, 3], [1, 4], [3, 2], [4], [1, 3, 6], [1]]
```

Note: `list.pop` by default pops the **last** element, so `list.pop(0)` is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this procedure for many lists, it might be nice to have a pre-made function. Here is one, written completely using HigherOrderPython.

```
from itertools import accumulate, tee, chain
from operator import itemgetter

i2, i3 = tee(accumulate([3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2]))
slicer = itemgetter(*map(slice, chain([None], i2), i3))

>>> print(slicer([6, 5, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 6, 1]))
([6, 5, 3], [1, 4], [3, 2], [4], [1, 3, 6], [1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using a generator is below.

```
def splitter(arr, lengths):
    assert(sum(lengths) == len(arr))
    i, s = 0, 0
    for l in lengths:
        s = s + l
        yield arr[i:s]
        i = i + l
```

It provides a bit more flexibility - the input can be most any sequence (list, tuple, string, ...) and the output can be cast to any suitable sequence.

```
my_list = [6, 5, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 6, 1]
my_lens = [3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]

ans = [x for x in splitter(my_list, my_lens)]
print(ans)
# [[6, 5, 3], [1, 4], [3, 2], [4], [1, 3, 6], [1]]

text = 'a quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'
lengths = [2, 6, 6, 4, 7, 5, 4, 5, 3]
print([x for x in splitter(text, lengths)])
# ['a ', 'quick ', 'brown ', 'fox ', 'jumped ', 'over ', 'the ', 'lazy ', 'dog']

my_tuple = (6, 5, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 6, 1)
my_lens = [3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]
print(tuple(x for x in splitter(my_tuple, my_lens)))
# ((6, 5, 3), (1, 4), (3, 2), (4,), (1, 3, 6), (1,))
```